# "Unable to open logs" error when I try to restart Apache

Tags: networking, apache2, log

When I try to start apache I get the following error

```
root@server11362:~# sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Restarting web server apache2 (98)Address already in use: 
   make_sock: could not bind to address 111.90.150.93:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

In fact the apache log contains no more information.

`netstat -tulpn` returns the following

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1098/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1414/redis-server
tcp        0      0 111.90.150.93:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1068/named      
tcp        0      0 111.90.150.92:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1068/named      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1068/named      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1194/postgres   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:44888           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      845/sshd        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1395/master     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1068/named      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6081            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1435/varnishd   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6082          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1434/varnishd   
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      1068/named      
tcp6       0      0 :::44888                :::*                    LISTEN      845/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      1395/master     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:953                 :::*                    LISTEN      1068/named      
tcp6       0      0 :::6081                 :::*                    LISTEN      1435/varnishd   
udp        0      0 111.90.150.93:53        0.0.0.0:*                           1068/named      
udp        0      0 111.90.150.92:53        0.0.0.0:*                           1068/named      
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           1068/named      
udp6       0      0 :::53
```

There is nothing on port 80 but I still cannot restart

Answer (score 9):

There is possibly more broken, because you also get

```
Unable to open logs
```

First of all, enable more logging

```
LogLevel debug
```

in your `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

Check your file permissions in `/var/log/apache2`.

I use often following command to debug:

```
strace -f apache2ctl start 2>&1|grep -v " ENOENT " | grep -Ee " E[A-Z]+"
```

It shows you excactly which calls are failed.

[Edit]

Another reason could produce overlapping listen adresses like:

```
Listen *:80
Listen 1.2.3.4:80
```

So you listen to all interfaces and the 2nd listen line tried to open an already opened port. Like described [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/bind.html).

Comment: file permissions /var/log/ are 755 and 640

Comment: And you log file?

Comment: 640                                                              This is /etc/apache2/sites-availab/courseworkbank.info

Comment: I meant, have looked also in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`?

Comment: respecting your other posts you should check your configs for the `Listen` keyword first.

Comment: In my case was the Listen. Agree with @user224465 about look first for Listen string on the conf. The most common problem if you can't find the PID listening is a double `Listen` value in the same vhost definition file. It can be overlapped, but is better to create separated vhost files to avoid that. After looking for that my apache has run again. Thank you.

Comment: This answer helps very little. Add "LogLevel debug" where? Add "Listen" where? To the global config? To the site config?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to start apache as a non-root user?  It's possible you don't have permission to bind Apache to ports lower than 1024 (generally only possible by the root-user) and the log files are owned by someone other than apache:apache, or owned by root, which would prevent Apache from opening them.

Check that /etc/apache2/logs is owned by the apache2 user and that you are starting the service as root (and make sure that User and Group in the /etc/apache2/conf/apache2.conf (or httpd.conf) is specified to the correct user).

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I had

```
Listen 192.168.0.101:80
```

in site configs.

But after PC restart my IP had changed to another (192.168.0.102). Fixing the IP address solved the problem.